# Queuing/caching insert queries before sending to DB in a batch

Tags: mysql, postgresql

In our environment we go through low periods of very few writes and high periods where it maxes out the DB.  We would like to introduce some form of queue or caching of inserts and doing it in a batch instead of individual inserts.  Anybody have any tips on this scenario?  Much appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there any specific piece of code where you're stuck?

Comment: Please provide [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: stackoverflow has become quite useless...  i'm asking for methodologies and what we should read up on before coding and getting minimum examples.  i'm not a student looking for homework assignment, i'm asking for any tips, pitfalls and advice from others who may have done something similar but if you want a minimum viable example to satisfy your useless comments here it is.       redish cache, wait til it has 100, then get all and batch insert.       thanks